# How to select option with double click?

Tags: html, jquery, html-select

How do I make a select option selectable by double click?

E.g. I double click "Option Text #3" and the value of option three shall be written into a hidden input field with id="selectedOption".

[image]

Comment: @RinoRaj this by javascript, not by jQuery, is different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `dblclick` this way:

```js
$('select option').dblclick(function() {
  $('#selectedOption').val(this.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="4">
  <option>Option # 1</option>
  <option>Option # 2</option>
  <option>Option # 3</option>
  <option>Option # 4</option>
</select>

<input type='text' id='selectedOption' value=''>
```

Comment: @RinoRaj what to do with that? That doesn't have jQuery.

Comment: It also doesn't work since it returns the entire select control html, not a value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$('select option').dblclick(function() {
  $('#selectedOption').val($("#select option:selected").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried the first answer that returns whole option html.

```js
$('select option').dblclick(function() {
  $('#selectedOption').val($(this).html());
});
```

use this one instead.